# List Problem : "Want to get a single list"

Tags: python, list

I want to count words from a dataframe. First I convert the dataframe's column to a list named **"lst"**. and the list is here-

```
['তাদের উত্তরের মধ্যে সামরিকতার ঝাঁজ ছিল',
 'ফোন করে যা শুনেছি তা তো মানুষ জানে আমরা তো এগুলো শুনতে অভ্যস্ত না']
```

Then I try this code-

```
lst1 = []
count=0

for i in lst:
  count += 1
  lst1.append(i.split(' '))

count
```

and the result of lst1[:2] is -

```
[['তাদের', 'উত্তরের', 'মধ্যে', 'সামরিকতার', 'ঝাঁজ', 'ছিল'],
 ['ফোন',
  'করে',
  'যা',
  'শুনেছি',
  'তা',
  'তো',
  'মানুষ',
  'জানে',
  'আমরা',
  'তো',
  'এগুলো',
  'শুনতে',
  'অভ্যস্ত',
  'না']]
```

But I want to a list where all words are in a single list. I want like this-

```
['তাদের', 'উত্তরের', 'মধ্যে', 'সামরিকতার', 'ঝাঁজ', 'ছিল', 'ফোন','করে','যা','শুনেছি','তা',......,'না']
```

How can I do this? What should I change to get this?

Comment: that's not a dataframe, that's just a list

Comment: After creating a list from the DataFrame, the question is **no longer anything to do with Pandas**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this. Here I use extend function. extend() is the function extended by lists in Python and hence can be used to perform this task. This function performs the inplace extension of the list. So it takes one by one from the **"lst1"** and adds to the final list.

```
lst_final = []

for i in lst1:
  lst_final.extend(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list.extend()` method to get a single list in the end.

```
lst = ['তাদের উত্তরের মধ্যে সামরিকতার ঝাঁজ ছিল',
 'ফোন করে যা শুনেছি তা তো মানুষ জানে আমরা তো এগুলো শুনতে অভ্যস্ত না']

lst1 = []
count=0

for i in lst:
    lst1.extend(i.split(' '))
```

Output:
`['তাদের', 'উত্তরের', 'মধ্যে', 'সামরিকতার', 'ঝাঁজ', 'ছিল', 'ফোন', 'করে', 'যা', 'শুনেছি', 'তা', 'তো', 'মানুষ', 'জানে', 'আমরা', 'তো', 'এগুলো', 'শুনতে', 'অভ্যস্ত', 'না']`

Answer (score 0):

`i.split(' ')` returns an array which you then append to an array making an array of arrays. I think you want something like `lst1.concat`

```
for i in lst:
  count += 1
  lst1.concat(i.split(' '))
```

Comment: Does list objects have concat property?

Comment: Pandas version of list objects does